# predict probability using R

Tags: r

The model that I created in R is:

```
fit <- lm(hired ~ educ + exper + sex, data=data)
```

what I am unsure of is how to fit to model to predict probability of interest where p = pr(hiring = 1).

Any help would be appreciated thanks,
Clay

Edit:
What role does glm play in my model then?(My answer below) Based on the edit that Jason made to Greg's answer I do not see what it does specifically.

Does my answer analyze the odds of being hired?

Comment: You may look up the `glm` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response liuminzhao. can you expand on this at all because I did look at the glm function and I was not sure how to do it. Sorry I am new to R.

Comment: Using a linear model to estimate probability, you'd have to make some assumptions.  I'm not sure a linear model is the best model here.  Instead you might consider using a Bayesian classifier.  You could just use fit$fit as an estimate of probability.

Comment: Would it be something like this?                                     fit <- glm(hired ~ educ + exper + sex, data=data),data=data,family=binomial())

Comment: I am open to suggestions MattD can you expand on your thought process though?

Comment: `glm` estimates a generalized linear model (e.g., [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), [probit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model), etc), `lm` estimates a linear model (i.e., ols). The answer I provided below shows how you can calculate predicted probabilities from an estimated `glm`; specifically, a logit model. Was that not what you were asking?

Answer (score 7):

For models estimated with `glm`, you can use the `predict` function to extract the linear predictor for each observation in your data set. You can then simply use the appropriate probability distribution function to get the predicted probability. For example, in the case of a logistic regression, use `plogis`. In other words, if `mod` is your model fit with `glm`:

```
> plogis(predict(mod))
```

will return the predicted probability for each observation in your data set, assuming you estimated a logistic model. If you need to calculate the predicted probability for points not in your data set, see the `newdata` option for `predict`. Note that `predict` can also provide standard errors at each point. Take a look at the documentation for `predict.glm` for more information.

EDIT: As suggested by Greg, you can use `type="response"` in the call to `predict` to get `plogis` for free:

```
> predict(mod, type="response")
```

Comment: Or use the arguments to the `predict` function for glm objects to automatically produce predictions on the desired scale.

Comment: Thanks guys for the insight I made an edit to my post.

Answer (score 0):

So I did my best to interpret the glm notes that I found and this is what I came up with.

```
 > test<-glm(hired ~ educ + exper + sex, data=data, family=binomial())
 > summary(test)

 Call:
 glm(formula = hired ~ educ + exper + sex, family = binomial(), 
     data = data)

 Deviance Residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
 -1.4380  -0.4573  -0.1009   0.1294   2.1804  

 Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
 (Intercept) -14.2483     6.0805  -2.343   0.0191 *
 educ          1.1549     0.6023   1.917   0.0552 .
 exper         0.9098     0.4293   2.119   0.0341 *
 sex           5.6037     2.6028   2.153   0.0313 *
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

 (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

     Null deviance: 35.165  on 27  degrees of freedom
 Residual deviance: 14.735  on 24  degrees of freedom
 AIC: 22.735

 Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```