# How to determine the probability that the predicted value reaches a certain value in R

Tags: r, probability

Based on the historical data from 2003 to 2018, I have predicted the data from 2019 to 2030 using  Applied Bayesian Econometrics method. Now I want to judge the probability that the predicted data in 2030 will reach 0.8. I wonder what method is used in R. Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Forecasting 11 years into the future from 15 years data is... foolish.

Comment: This is more of a methods question than a programming question. (At least until you share some code.) Might be more at home at stats.stackexchange than here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agreed, and also think that this is less about a specific method in R, but more about specifics methods in general *and* their implementation, so voting to move to stats.stackexchange.

Comment: If you have already fit a Bayesian model, this should be a pretty simple simulation from your posterior distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that in order to do what you want you can use the **predict** function to extract the linear predication for each observation in the data set. You can then simply use the appropriate probability distribution function to get the predicted probability. For example, in the case of a logistic regression, use plogis. In other words, if mod is your model fit with glm:

```
plogis(predict(mod))
```

will return the predicted probability for each observation in your data set, assuming you estimated a logistic model. If you need to calculate the predicted probability for points not in your data set, see the newdata option for predict. Note that predict can also provide standard errors at each point. Take a look at the documentation for predict.glm for more information (using **help(predict)**):

```
predict(mod, type="response")
```

Adapted from Jason Morgan:[predict probability using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327014/predict-probability-using-r/13328193)

Also, for a logistic regression, the function usage follows:

```
predict(object, newdata = NULL,
            type = c("link", "response", "terms"),
            se.fit = FALSE, dispersion = NULL, terms = NULL,
            na.action = na.pass, ...)
```

And you can try to implement an available R as:

```
predict(budworm.lg, data.frame(ldose = ld,
   sex = factor(rep("M", length(ld)), levels = levels(sex))),
   type = "response")
```

For the data base *Venables and Ripley (2002, pp. 190-2.)*. Specifically, the you can use the following code:

```
require(graphics)

## example from Venables and Ripley (2002, pp. 190-2.)
ldose <- rep(0:5, 2)
numdead <- c(1, 4, 9, 13, 18, 20, 0, 2, 6, 10, 12, 16)
sex <- factor(rep(c("M", "F"), c(6, 6)))
SF <- cbind(numdead, numalive = 20-numdead)
budworm.lg
budworm.lg <- glm(SF ~ sex*ldose, family = binomial)
summary(budworm.lg)

plot(c(1,32), c(0,1), type = "n", xlab = "dose",
     ylab = "prob", log = "x")
text(2^ldose, numdead/20, as.character(sex))
ld <- seq(0, 5, 0.1)
lines(2^ld, predict(budworm.lg, data.frame(ldose = ld,
                                           sex = factor(rep("M", length(ld)), levels = levels(sex))),
                    type = "response"))
lines(2^ld, predict(budworm.lg, data.frame(ldose = ld,
                                           sex = factor(rep("F", length(ld)), levels = levels(sex))),
                    type = "response"))
```